# how to show different effects in nivoslider dynamically

Tags: nivo-slider

i am using nivoslider and have 4 different slides and for each slide i want different effect as slideInLeft,fade,fold and sliceUpDown for each different one. my slider is running well,it's just i needed different sliding effect for each slides.i am using codeigniter. any help/suggestions are welcome.thanks

```
<img src="uploaded_files/banner/<?php echo $banner->file ?>" data-thumb="uploaded_files/banner/<?php echo $banner->file ?>" alt="" data-transition="slideInLeft"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is simple.i just to have to add some conditions as follows.

```
$i = 1;
if($i=='1') $transition = 'slideInLeft';
                            elseif($i=='2') $transition='fade';
                            elseif($i=='3') $transition='fold';
                            else $transition = 'sliceUpDown';
                                ?>
                                <img src="uploaded_files/banner/<?php echo $banner->file ?>" data-thumb="uploaded_files/banner/<?php echo $banner->file ?>" alt=""  data-transition="<?php echo $transition?>"/>      


                     $i++;
```

it worked but if someone has some better idea than this one,please do share.